# Getting a url parameter into asp.net label

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to automatically set the text of a asp:label to a url parameter but it does not seem to work.

This is the code I have:

```
     <asp:Label ID="lblHouse" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Request.QueryString["Selection"] %>' 
        Font-Bold="True" 
        Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label> <br /> <br />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use <%=  %> (instead of <%#) and put it inside of the asp:label tag, instead of the Text property:

```
            <asp:Label ID="lblHouse" runat="server"  
            Font-Bold="True"  
            Font-Size="Large"><%= Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString["Selection"]) %></asp:Label>
```

Comment: ahhh Beautiful I knew I was missing something. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: For more info on other options see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738122/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs

Comment: test it with Selection=<script>alert('hello')</script>

Comment: @Aristos - that's an excellent point. You should scrub those inputs with a Server.HTMLEncode - I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

Hey Try this its working fine

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHouse" runat="server"          
        Font-Bold="True"  
        Font-Size="Large"><%= Request.QueryString["Selection"] %></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# ... %>
```

evaulates when you data bind an object.

try

```
lblHouse.DataBind()
```

or try using

```
<%= ... %>
```

Comment: "<%= ... %>" will not work, it will throw an exception or return nothing depending on your " and ' uses.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the text in your code behind file

```
lblHouse.Text = Request.QueryString("Selection").ToString
```

Comment: Yeah I know about the code behind but I am wondering if there is a way of doing it in the aspx page.