# asp control block wont let me nest a codeblock. makes sense, but how do i fix it

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

```
 <tr runat="server" >
   <th><%= Resources.bicweb_resources.BORDER_STYLE %></th>
   <td>
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id = "borderContent" class = "attribute" >
       <asp:ListItem value = "NULL">
       </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value = "0" >
         <%= Resources.bicweb_resources.FALSE %>
       </asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem value = "1">
         <%= Resources.bicweb_resources.TRUE %>
       </asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

You can see that i set stuff inside an ...

the ListItems are not runatserver, so i was thinking of a way to make it work to place 3 items into where they are suppose to be.

The error comes from trying to render a control which has a block inside to render at server time.  Im trying to figure out if i should select the dropdownlist on serverside, and then iterate through the child controls or something.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738122/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs/8738555#8738555

Comment: @TimMedora im looking through the first link at MSDN to see what they are saying about it

Comment: Second link may be clearer...basically, if you want to execute code inside a server control tag, an expression builder is a good way to do it.

Comment: The first link actually was what game me the answer.   <%$ Resources: bicweb_resources, SAMPLE %> did what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codeblocks are wrong for the resource file.

Your code block:

```
 <%= Resources.bicweb_resouces.TRUE %>
```

What it should be:

```
 <%$ Resources: bicweb_resources, TRUE %>
```

Instead of nesting them in tags, you can also use the TEXT attribute of the control to populate the data.

Information from:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad(v=vs.100).aspx