# OnClientClick event doesn't register javascript alert from code-behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Alright, I have an embarrassingly simple question that hopefully has an embarrassingly simple answer. I am trying to get an asp:ImageButton to display an alert message that contains variables from my codebehind. Here's the overly simplified version of the code:

```
public string AlertMe
{
    get
    {
        return "alert('hi');";
    }
}
```

Now when I try and access it this way:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/img.ico" OnClientClick='<%=AlertMe%>'/>
```

I see a postback, but no alert message, as if it can't access my property at all. Meanwhile, these 2 lines:

```
<%=AlertMe%><br />
<a onclick="<%=AlertMe%>">click this</a>
```

both work fine and dandy. (The first displays the code for the javascript alert, and the second fires the alert with no issues.)

So my big question is: why does the OnClientClick event for an asp control fail to register the alert? Is there an obvious flaw I'm missing, or do I really need to register the entire event from code-behind?

Comment: I wouldn't continue down this path of embedding your behavioral client-side Javascript with your compiled server-side code. I prefer to use unobtrusive Javascript (jQuery?) in an external file, in an effort to keep things logically separated  If needed you can use server-side constructs to determine which .js file(s) to include.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the input. Hopefully this is something I can ease myself into as I become more comfortable with Javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `<%= ... %>` syntax to set attributes of a Server Control.  To set dynamic attributes on Server Controls, you have to set it in code.

```
this.btn.OnClientClick = this.AlertMe;
```

This is because `<%= ... %>` is a shortcut for `Response.Write()`.  So, it isn't called until *after* the aspx has been parsed, evaluated, and rendering has begun.  By then it's too late.

As an alternative to setting the value in the code behind, you could use this quasi-declarative technique:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/img.ico" />
<%
btn.OnClientClick = <%=AlertMe%>;
%>
```

There are other ways to get around it.  [This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8738681/361684) discusses several approaches you can take.  I can't find any "official" reference (eg, msdn) that mentions this specifically, but I didn't look that hard.  Here are a couple of blog posts that discuss the issue as well:

- Blog post by Jim Black: [Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs](http://jblack.wordpress.com/2006/12/15/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs/)
- Blog post at weblogs.asp.net: [Use ExpressionBuilder To Avoid “Server tags cannot contain <% … %> constructs”](http://weblogs.asp.net/alnurismail/archive/2009/04/18/use-expressionbuilder-to-avoid-server-tags-cannot-contain-lt-gt-constructs.aspx)

Or [google it with bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=Server+tags+cannot+contain+%3C%25+%25%3E+constructs&first=13&FORM=PORE) for more fun reading.

Comment: Any chance you have a reference to explain this behavior? I'm sure the fix will work, but I'm really curious about why server controls would have this limitation. The issue is compounded because the button is buried in the SelectedItemTemplate of a ListView, and is a real pain to get to.

Comment: @MadHenchbot - I added some links to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else encountering this issue, I ran across this blog from way back when:
http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

I found the sections about Expression Builders and ViewState concerns to be particularly informative.

Answer (score -1):

I think its a quoting problem.  Try

```
OnClientClick="<%=AlertMe%>"
```

Comment: I've tried it with both types of quotes, but to no avail. When I type in the alert directly, it works, but the control can't seem to handle the <%= %> notation.