# Dynamic Id on asp:Literal Cntrl

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I want to add Id's to some ctrls as below, depending on the id's I want to change the server-side values for these controls.
But i am getting compile time error -not a valid identifier.
I know that this can be done in code behind but just wanted to know if it is possible to do it on apsx page.

Thanks for the concern

```
 <asp:Literal ID="ltrlTotalAmount_<%= trPlanYear.toString()%>" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738122/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs. Pretty sure the solutions won't work for an ID, but it may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign an ID like that; the ID must be statically defined.  You could use a client-side element instead.  Even  client-side input elements can be read by using the Request.Form collection on postback.  Though you have to re-render them manually on every page postback.