# Getting error Error-Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<input id="tbxPopupCode" type="text" runat="server" value="<%= Request.QueryString["code"].Replace("-"," ") %>" />
```

I m getting an error:

> Server tags cannot contain <% … %> constructs

I need to replace the value from `Request.QueryString["code"]` and bind into textbox value.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738122/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs

Comment: That questions are different

Comment: @PrinceAntonyG you are true with that, but the error is the same and the answer reveals the solution.

Comment: yeah correct, same error message

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, the exception message is pretty clear:
You can not have `runat="server"` and `<%= %>`.

There are some workarouns for this (eg `<%# %>`), but why not simply setting the value on the code-behind like `this.tbxPopupCode.Value = ...`?

Comment: while building that page i got the error. i removed the runat=server now its is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it doesn't apply to this specific question, but I also received this error when I included the construct for an HTML tag attribute inside of a PlaceHolder control.

Comment: I am listing another plausible cause for the same error. It is vitally important for people who are googling the error and looking for the solution that way.