# Div element hide and show

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a hidden div element.

```
<div class= "CTL" id="CTL" runat="server" style="display:none">
<p class ="divider">
CTL
    </p>
            <asp:Button ID="CTL_button" runat="server" Text="View CTL" 
            onclick="CTL_button_Click" />
</div>
```

I am trying to make the div element appear or stay hidden based on an SQL value returned on page Load:-

```
   window.onload= function show_CTL() {
    if("<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>" == "True"){
       document.getElementById('CTL').style.display ="block";
     }
     else{
         // document.getElementById('CTL').style.display ="none";
         }
```

But the div element remains shown regardless of value returned...

It seems like only the true part of the loop gets executed...

Comment: Can you make sure that the id is 'CTL'? asp.net could be changing the id's

Comment: (just realized ASP) when your webpage is rendered. look at the source code (right click and "View Page Source") what is displayed between the quotes in the raw html instead of `<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>`? Also check if your div is the only one with the id CTL

Comment: the funny thing is I added, both if and else statements to show the div element and the div element still didn't show up...

Comment: the returned value for <%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%> is 'True'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the condition to a `Boolean` in JavaScript you can do it like this:

```
window.onload = function show_CTL() {
    var el = document.getElementById('CTL');

    if(Boolean("<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>") && el){
        el.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        el.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

If the Boolean object has no initial value, or if the passed value is one of the following:

```
0
-0
null
""
false
undefined
NaN
```

the object is set to false. For any other value it is set to true (even with the string "false")!

Now I wonder, why not simply add the condition inside the `visible` attribute?

```
<div class="CTL" id="CTL" runat="server" visible=<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>></div>
```

No JavaScript needed this way.

Comment: I get an error with your second approach:- Server tags cannot contain <%= %>

Comment: For the second option, remove the `runat` attribute or use `<%#%>` or add it in de codebehind as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699895/getting-error-error-server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs)

Comment: For the first option, are you sure it is unique? Do you get any JavaScript errors if you remove the `&& el` from the condition?

Also, is this code part of a repeater? Are you databinding stuff? Cause that's important information if it's the case.

Comment: The funny thing is, now my code for display is working, but the problem is in the if statement:-

even when the returned value for IsCTL False, my code still enters the display part of the loop....

Comment: If you cast the Boolean you don't need to check if it's true or false, JavaScript renders it true or false => `if (Boolean(True) == 'True')` will result in false! Leave the operators out of it. Just refering to your comment on Taimour's post.

Comment: You can always try `console.log('<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>')` or `alert('<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>')`.

Comment: Alert message : "False"... yet div element shown.:)

Comment: see my update as `Boolean('False')` will result to true, unfortunately.

Comment: ok finally solved:-

if (("<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>") == "True") {...}

This works for both False and True values.

Comment: I will select your answer for taking the trouble to troubleshoot this with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use display:none to hide the div in first place

```
<div class= "CTL" id="CTL" style="display:none" runat="server">
<p class ="divider">
CTL
    </p>
            <asp:Button ID="CTL_button" runat="server" Text="View CTL" 
            onclick="CTL_button_Click" />
</div>
```

then you can show it with

```
   document.getElementById('CTL').style.display ="block";
```

Comment: `visible="false"` must be something of ASP.Net which results the same as `style="display: none;"`.

Comment: Incidentally, you can also use `visibility:hidden` and `style.visiblity='visible'`: http://jsfiddle.net/w8nt4/

Comment: No luck using either. and yes it is part of ASP.NET

Comment: then try console.log("<%=_CurrentUser.IsCTL%>") before your if block to see what is being returned

Comment: @TimVermaelen Setting something to not visible in an ASP.NET server control results in no HTML being rendered to the client. That's why if you want the HTML rendered to the client but to be hidden, you should use `style="display:none"` as Taimour suggested.

Comment: Ah yes, makes sense. Although the OP states `I have a hidden div element`. Hidden or not rendered?

Comment: @TaimourTanveer Hey your suggestion worked, however during my if statement:- 

Even when my returned boolean value is if(Boolean("False") == true), my code still enters the true part of the code....any ideas?

Comment: it should be "True" rather than true

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is changing the IDs, thats why you have to take the clientID of your element.

```
document.getElementById("<%= CTL.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: I don't believe that's the case in this particular div but you are right about the `ClientID`. => `ClientIDMode="static"`

Answer (score 1):

`visible` and `display` are 2 different css property, 
you set `visible` first, but later you change `display`, 
you should change visible, not display,
of cause you can use display instead of visible in the first place.