# C# Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code :

```
<div class="detailBox">
                    <div class="actionBox">
                        <ul class="commentList">
                        <%
                            foreach (System.Data.DataRow drow in members.Rows)
                            {
                        %>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="commentText">
                                        <span><%= drow["nume_user"] %></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-xs" runat="server" OnClick="deleteMember" Text="Elimina" CommandArgument="<%= drow["id"] %>" />
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                        <%
                            }
                        %>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

I don't know why I get this error `Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.` when I want to give `CommandArgument` the value of `drow["id"]`, how can I pass this variable to the code behind when I click on the button ?

EDIT
And the code behind that's being executed when I click the button:

```
 protected void deleteMember(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GroupsConnString"].ToString();
            var argument = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;

            Response.Write(argument);
            if (argument != null)
            {
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
                comm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM app_groups.users_groups_leg WHERE id = " + argument;

                int result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();  //here you will get the no.of rows effected 

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: replace the double quotes with single quotes. CommandArgument='<%= drow["id"] %>'

Comment: CommandArgument='<%= drow["id"] %>'

Comment: Why don't you do that code behind. Can you post the relevant code section.

Comment: @Rahul I put the code behind also, have a look at it :)

Comment: the way you are doing doesn't seems right. Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738122/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs. It's what you want to do actually.

Comment: @Rahul, I don't think that's what I want to do, I just want to pass an argument which I obtain iterating through that array when I press the button... asp is really crappy, I'm a newbie in asp. I have a PHP oriented thinking and in PHP that would be a way you would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `<%# %>` to switch between c# and html. So your code should be

```
<div class="detailBox">
                <div class="actionBox">
                    <ul class="commentList">
                    <%#
                        foreach (System.Data.DataRow drow in members.Rows)
                        {
                    %>
                            <li>
                                <div class="commentText">
                                    <span><%= drow["nume_user"] %></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <asp:Button ID="deleteButton" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-xs" runat="server" OnClick="deleteMember" Text="Elimina" CommandArgument="<%= drow["id"] %>" />
                                </div>
                            </li>
                    <%#
                        }
                    %>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: it won't work, it doesn't recognize `foreach` statement