# Put variables and statements into text of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to figure out how to put something else than just static string into `text` attribute of `<asp:button>`. Following code:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="updateList" Text=<%= isEditing ? Resources.Labels.Update : Resources.Labels.Insert %> />
```

returns

> Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: @MarcGravell that makes button with text literally ``<%= ... %>``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server tags cannot contain <% … %> constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738122/server-tags-cannot-contain-constructs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Databinding expression for that `<%# %>`:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="updateList" Text='<%# isEditing ? Resources.Labels.Update : Resources.Labels.Insert %>' />
```

But for it to work outside a GridView, Repeater etc you have to call `DataBind()` manually.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```